# Configure static IP on eth1

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, ip, ifconfig

I want to configure my eth1 interface to have a static IP, even if the cable is not plugged in. Is that at all doable?
I need that as I want to eventually configure a DHCP server (isc-dhcp-server) to give an IP address to a device that will be connected to my machine via this interface. The device, however might not be plugged in all the time. And it seems like DHCP server will refuse to start if that interface doesn't have an IP/subnet. (please correct me if I am wrong).
My `/etc/network/interfaces` has the following entry for eth1:

```
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.20.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.20.1
```

Still when running `ifconfig` the eth1 doesn't have an IP assigned.
I was always completely ignorant in terms of networking etc, so I might be missing something very obvious.
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you restart the networking service after making the change(s) to `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: address and gateway have the same value?

Comment: I did restart networking service, and I did down/up of the eth1 interface.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio I took that from [here](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html). I am trying to do a very similar thing, except my "host B" would not have a static IP, but rather one assigned by DHCP server.

Comment: looks like a valid configuration for Debian. Though you didn't say what distribution you have. It doesn't happen to run Network Manager or something similar which would want to control everything? What happens if you remote that odd gateway assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write before this:

```
 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet static
     address 192.168.20.1
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.20.1
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `auto eth1` line :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to activate your interface:

```
ifup eth1
```

Other things regarding your configuration:

- Add `auto eth1` so that you don't have to execute `ifup` manually
- As noticed by Zumo de Vidrio, your gateway address is useless, if not wrong. Put in the IP address of the box that connects your Raspberry-Pi to the Internet.

Comment: I did restart eth1 (`ifconfig eth1 down/up`). Also, I don't think that I want to set the gateway as the box that connects me to the internet. Eventually I will aim to redirect all traffic from eth1 to tun0 (OpenVPN connection that I have already running). From examples around internet I saw this done using iptables.

Comment: Your VPN needs a gateway. Maybe it's eth0's gateway? In that case, remove the gateway line for eth1. As for `ifup`, did you try `ifdown --force eth1` before `ifup eth1`? Also, did you get any error message while ifup'ing ? Does `ifconfig` show `eth1`? Else, does `ifconfig -a` show your IP? Finally, if could help if you show us your whole `/etc/network/interfaces` config file, can you update your question please?